# counting unique words in a string without using an array

Tags: java, string

So my task is to write a program that counts the number of words and unique words in a given string that we get from the user without using arrays.
I can do the first task and was wondering how I could go about doing the second part.
For counting the number of words in the string I have

```
boolean increment = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputPhrase.length(); i++){
           if(validChar(inputPhrase.charAt(i))) //validChar(char c) is a simple method that returns a valid character{
                   increment = true;
           }
           else if(increment){
                   phraseWordCount ++;
                   increment = false;
           }
    }
    if(increment) phraseWordCount++; //in the case the last word is a valid character
```

(originally i left this out and was off by one word)
to count unique words can I somehow modify this?

Comment: Are you allowed to uses `Collection`s, e.g. `Set`?

Comment: @ifLoop If he's not allowed to use arrays, probably he cannot use Collection as well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun What exactly is the purpose of your comment? I am clever enough to  assume that by myself, but since I am no visionary, I have to ask him. Are you a visionary?

Comment: You must somehow register your strings, so I don't think that what you are looking for is possible. Unless you are just restricted at not using array but able to use other storing class ... but in this case you have the answer ..

Comment: @ifLoop Why are you attacking me? Relax my friend.. take it easy and smile.. No need to be that aggressive.

Comment: @ifLoop If I had a purpose from my comment, I **WILL** be sure that you'll get exactly the message I want you to get, trust me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I am not attacking, just aksing. If you perceive this as an attack you may want to learn a bit about stylistic /rethorical devices ... take it easy, take a break.

Comment: @ifLoop Then your way of asking is a little bit aggressive. Anyway, I'm super relaxed this morning :) Have a good day.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Please lecture BaptisteL as well. To get a point: Serius dude, If OP is asked (an not you), let OP answer.  Have a nice day too!

Comment: Have you considered writing the words to a file and then reading them back?

Comment: @ifLoop I wasn't answering, that's why I said "probably", that's what I thought.. I'm not speaking in his name :) Anyway, we'll wait to see what OP says.. cheers

Comment: @Levenal This would be much overhead. If you are allowed to use the Collections API you could use a `Scanner` and for example a `Map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a suggestion how to do it without arrays:

1) Read every char until a blank is found and add this char to a second `String`.
2) If a blank is found, add it (or another token to seperate words) to the second `String`.
2a) Read every word from second `String` comparing it to the current word from he input `String`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String input = "This is a sentence that is containing three times the word is";
    final char   token = '#';

    String processedInput  = "";
    String currentWord     = "";
    int    wordCount       = 0;
    int    uniqueWordCount = 0;

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            processedInput += c;
            currentWord    += c;
        } else {
            processedInput += token;
            wordCount++;

            String  existingWord      = "";
            int     occurences        = 0;

            for (char c1 : processedInput.toCharArray()) {
                if (c1 != token) {
                    existingWord += c1;
                } else {
                    if (existingWord.equals(currentWord)) {
                        occurences++;
                    }

                    existingWord = "";
                }
            }

            if (occurences <= 1) {
                System.out.printf("New word: %s\n", currentWord);
                uniqueWordCount++;
            }

            currentWord = "";
        }
    }
    wordCount++;


    System.out.printf("%d words total, %d unique\n", wordCount, uniqueWordCount);
}
```

Output

```
New word: This
New word: is
New word: a
New word: sentence
New word: that
New word: containing
New word: three
New word: times
New word: the
New word: word
12 words total, 10 unique
```

Comment: did you tried the code before? try input string "is is is" "3 words, 2 unique.." i don't think so

Comment: @DanP. I think I messed up the inner for loop, I had to check against `token` not `' '`. Fixed that. But there are other bugs.. I'll redo that one -.-

Comment: maybe there is a definition error i think. the "is" is not an unique word, because it is repeated... but the questioniar should clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Collections API you can count words with the following method:

```
private int countWords(final String text) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
    Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        uniqueWords.add(scanner.next());
    }

    scanner.close();

    return uniqueWords.size();
}
```

If it is possible that you get normal sentences with punctuation marks you can change the second line to:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z\\s]", "").toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a word ends `findUpTo` checks if the word is contained in the input before the start of that word. So `"if if if"` would count as one unique and three total words.

```
/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/22981210/1266906
 */
public class UniqueWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputPhrase = "one two ones two three one";
        countWords(inputPhrase);
    }

    private static void countWords(String inputPhrase) {
        boolean increment = false;
        int wordStart = -1;
        int phraseWordCount = 0;
        int uniqueWordCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputPhrase.length(); i++){
            if(validChar(inputPhrase.charAt(i))) { //validChar(char c) is a simple method that returns a valid character{
                increment = true;
                if(wordStart == -1) {
                    wordStart = i;
                }
            } else if(increment) {
                phraseWordCount++;
                final String lastWord = inputPhrase.substring(wordStart, i);
                boolean unique = findUpTo(lastWord, inputPhrase, wordStart);
                if(unique) {
                    uniqueWordCount++;
                }
                increment = false;
                wordStart = -1;
            }
        }
        if(increment) {
            phraseWordCount++; //in the case the last word is a valid character
            final String lastWord = inputPhrase.substring(wordStart, inputPhrase.length());
            boolean unique = findUpTo(lastWord, inputPhrase, wordStart);
            if(unique) {
                uniqueWordCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Words: "+phraseWordCount);
        System.out.println("Unique: "+uniqueWordCount);
    }

    private static boolean findUpTo(String needle, String haystack, int lastPos) {
        boolean previousValid = false;
        boolean unique = true;
        for(int j = 0; unique && j < lastPos - needle.length(); j++) {
            final boolean nextValid = validChar(haystack.charAt(j));
            if(!previousValid && nextValid) {
                // Word start
                previousValid = true;
                for (int k = 0; k < lastPos - j; k++) {
                    if(k == needle.length()) {
                        // We matched all characters. Only if the word isn't finished it is unique
                        unique = validChar(haystack.charAt(j+k));
                        break;
                    }
                    if (needle.charAt(k) != haystack.charAt(j+k)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                previousValid = nextValid;
            }
        }
        return unique;
    }

    private static boolean validChar(char c) {
        return Character.isAlphabetic(c);
    }
}
```